# How to loop with the same variable but different value

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I'm display some elements with JSON

Before starting here is the order I am supposed to have: toto-> titi-> tata-> trtr-> tktk-> tztz

I have to post the next job on each iteration knowing that the first one is toto

So for now I have:
toto
titi
tata

And I can not see how to loop to see all the rest.

```
function getall() {
    ajaxGet(".../toto/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}
getall(); 
function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
    ...
}

function recover(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    
            console.log("toto");
            //toto
            console.log(group.name);    
            //titi
            ajaxGet2("..."+group.name+"/api/json?pretty=true", recover2);    

        });          
}

function ajaxGet2(url, callback) {
    ....
}

function recover2(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {        
            console.log(group.name);
            //tata       
    });       
}

/* JSON Downstreamproject for toto 
"downstreamProjects" : [
{
  "_class" : "****",
  "name" : "titi",
  "url" : "https://**/***/titi/",
  "color" : "blue"
}
],
*/
```

Actual result:
toto
titi
tata

Expected result (with loop):
toto
titi
tata
trtr
tktk
tztz

Comment: I am having problems understanding what you mean, but if you mean that the order of variables used for the ajax calls doesn't match the resulting order of the of the ajax callbacks: ajax execution is asynchronous.

If you want to keep the order, you might want to use promises and chain them.

Comment: To put it simply, I have jobs and I have to display the correct order of these jobs
I just know that the first job is toto and I can post the next job.
So I made a rough draft and I know that the order is: toto tata trtr tktk tztz
the downstreamProjects function displays the next job.

Comment: What happens is that you fire six asynchronous function calls:
toto-> titi-> tata-> trtr-> tktk-> tztz
While these sich calls are being executed you receive three ajax responses
toto-> titi-> tata->
Then your process ends, because it ends when your calls are done with firing the ajax calls.
You need to make the program wait until it has received all ajax responses.
There are a few techniques to handle such situations. To use promises would be the preferred way to aproach your problem. I would also recommend using a library like axios for http requests which already is promisified.

Comment: Ok I try to do something ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop ajaxGet call inside getAll() function.
like below:

```
let group = [toto, titi, tata, trtr, tktk, tztz]    
function getall() {
for(let groupName in group) {
    ajaxGet(".../<groupName>/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not using a array and I know only the first one (toto)

Comment: @KoorKoor28 So how do you get other groupName? I mean how they're generated?

Comment: and the function downstramprojet display the next job, so I need to do a loop

Comment: @KoorKoor28 could you share code for downstramProject as well as sample JSON?

Comment: The DownstreamProject is already in the script into the function recover and I put the JSON for more comprehension, thanks